# Adding login screen in front of Cocoa Touch Tab Bar Application for IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, tabbar

Still getting my head around things here. I'm not even close, but anyways.... I have a TabBar application created from Xcode. It works I have three tab views, that I know how to manipulate, etc.

I'd like to put a 'login' nib file in front of this whole thing, requiring a user to answer a (hardcoded for now) username and password. If you get that right, then, render the tab portion, allowing them to click around.

I have another application that I've written that does the username and password part, I'm having trouble taking the logic from there, and putting it in front of the TabApplication piece.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your AppDelegate, at the end of the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method you'll see this:

```
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Simply initialize your login view controller and add it after the tabcontroller, like this:

```
initialScreenViewController = [[InitialScreenViewController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
[window addSubview:initialScreenViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

In you login viewcontroller, after authenticating the user you can hide it like this:

```
[self.parentViewController.view setHidden:YES];
```

which allows you to show it again if you have a logout feature.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot tomorrow. I'm a c# developer normally, so the syntax, and ideology around how this stuff all works is still forming in my mushy brain. Thank you.

Comment: So when it loads, the tab view is loaded, and I only see the bottom of it, the LoginView is still 'on top'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Example of what I'm seeing. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10462461/Screen%20shot%202010-12-10%20at%208.32.15%20AM.png you can see the tab bar under the UI view at the bottom.

Comment: Is that before you've dismissed the login with the setHidden line? If so, it means your login view needs to be taller, looks like about 20 pixels. Or is is after you've dismissed the login with the setHidden line?

Comment: After! - I call setHidden:YES and the screenshot is what I end up with. 
I started with a TabView project from xcode. added a third tab, hooked it all up correctly ( I think) and then, add a LoginViewController, and LoginView Nib. I load the loginview nib as you said, and hooked up all the UI elements for the LoginView, right now user/password is hardcoded to check for credentials, and once I get those right I do the setHidden, and I still see the loginView, and the TabView (partially as seen in the screen shot.) Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me:
[self.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Glad you solved it, though I'm uncertain as to why my suggestion didn't work, as I have a couple of projects that use the same method. Still, good news.

Comment: How do you deal with _window.rootViewController_ property in newer iOS versions?

Comment: @Stas Unfortunately I haven't had to do this for a while, so I'm not certain.

Answer (score 16):

The standard way is the following:

- Package everything related to login screen into a view and a `UIViewController` subclass which manages that.
- Present that view modally in the app delegate in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` by calling

  ```
  LoginController*loginController= ... ; // create the view controller for the login screen
  [self.tabController presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
  ```

This way, the animation between the transition etc. is automatically handled.

You can later dismiss it after you successfully logs in. It can be done from inside the `LoginController` by

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However, I often need to do additional setup once the logging-in is done. So, I would first tell the app delegate that the login is done, and then perform

```
[self.tabController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

from the app delegate. Then I can perform additional tasks there.

To communicate back to the app delegate,  I would use [`NSNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i), but that might be a bit difficult for you.

One way which might be easier to understand (but uglier to my taste) is to define a method, say `loginDone` in the app delegate.
Then, inside the `LoginViewController`, you can do

```
MyAppDelegate*appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate loginDone];
```

Comment: How do I dismiss it from the LoginControllerView?

Comment: Do `[self.tabController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` from the app delegate, after the login is complete. You can do `[self.parentViewController dissmissModalViewControllerAnimcated:YES]` from inside the method of `LoginViewController`, but in any case you need to tell the app delegate that you performed the login successfully. I prefer dismissing it from the app delegate.

Comment: Sorry, trying to understand your explanation. So in my LoginViewController, once they pass authentication, how do I pass that event back to the app delegate? Thank you.

Comment: `presentModalViewController` is deprecated, use `[self.tabController presentViewController:self.loginController animated:YES completion:nil];` instead. In this case animation looks ugly, because tabController must appear first and only after it appears on screen it should present loginController. So I prefer to pass `animated:NO`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting with the default tab bar application you can do it like this:

- In the MainWindow.xib, create a UIView that contains all the stuff you want to have on your password screen
- Hook whatever you need up to IBOutlets in the AppDelegate, and write the method that checks if the password is valid.
- In the applicationDidFinishLaunching method, replace `[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];` with `[window addSubview:/*whatever you called the view with the password stuff in it*/];`
- If the user enters the correct password do this:

`[passView removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];`

And you should be in the regular tab bar application.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do the following:

In App Delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
FirstViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
ThirdViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController1, navController2, navController3];

LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *loginNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = loginNavController;
```

Then after getting an authentication callback, you can have something like this in your App Delegate:

```
- (void)setAuthenticatedState:(BOOL)authenticated
{
    if (authenticated == YES) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
        });
    }else{
        // Stuff
    }
}
```