# Adding login screen in front of tab bar in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have read [Adding login screen in front of Cocoa Touch Tab Bar Application for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406426/adding-login-screen-in-front-of-objective-c-tab-bar-application-for-ios) but think the tab bar application code must have significantly changed in Xcode 4.

Steps I followed:

- I created a new tab bar application
- I created a new group called Login
- Within Login I created a Login.xib file with the fields and button
- I created a new view controller (.h and .m files) called LoginViewController
- I clicked on the xib file and made sure it's files owner was set to LoginViewController
- In LoginViewController.h and .m I created the appropriate IBAction for the login button and IBOutlets for the username and password fields and wired them up.
- I went into the app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to figure out how to change it to launch my .xib file first but stuck there.

Comment: Using Xcode 4 doesn't change your code unless you are using a method that got depreciated in iOS 4.3 SDK.

Comment: I didn't mean that it changed my code.  Just that it seems the example that they are speaking about in the first answer seems to have changed.  In xcode 4, when I create a new tab application from the template, it no longer does: [window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

Comment: They just cleaned up the code.  You can still add your login view. For example: `[self.window addSubview:initialScreenViewController.view];`

Comment: I tried changing it to: loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];
    [self.window addSubview:LoginViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
But it gives an error on each line that mentions LoginViewController which is my view controller for my Login.xib file.

Comment: You need to edit your question and post the code you have for `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.  Here's what I did:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```