# Login View in tabbed application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I build a login view in a tabbed application? I'm new in ios development. I have read a lot through the internet but no one just posts the code I can understand. Any help is appreciated =).

Comment: your approach is not correct. Dont try to find the code. try to find a  tutorial or guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did This to solve my question:

My rootViewController is my registration view, then I set a button with implements a custom segue:

```
-(IBAction)button {
    NSLog(@"username: %@, password: %@, passwordrt: %@", username.text, password.text, passwordrt.text);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tabBar" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a related post here: [Adding login screen in front of Cocoa Touch Tab Bar Application for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406426/adding-login-screen-in-front-of-cocoa-touch-tab-bar-application-for-ios?rq=1)

I prefer writing like this tho.

```
[window setRootController:tabBarCon];
if (notLogedIn) {
    loginViewController = [[InitialScreenViewController alloc] init];
    [tabBarCon.view addSubview:loginViewController.view];
}
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

- (bool)notLoggedIn {
     //check if there is any sessions exists in local storage
}
```

If your content relates to the user account, remember to implement a method to reload the the content after login.