# Recursive calls to viewDidLoad, crashing

Tags: ios, xcode

**in loggerViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:mainView]; // <-- Problem is here
}
```

loggingViewController is an iVar of my appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    .
    .
    loggingViewController = [[loggerViewController alloc] init];
    [loggingViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
//    [loggingViewController loadView];
    [self.view addSubview:loggingViewController.view];

}
```

I was expecting my AppDelegate to call loggingViewController, which in turn, set up it's own subviews inside and it would be done. But instead the viewDidLoad gets called recursively I don't understand why?

Comment: The reason for recursive calling is your `self.view` is `nil` and hence it is try to call again and again. Are you doing something else in your loadView method or so? If you just comment out `[loggingViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];`, is it happening?

Comment: Yeah I notice now that the AppDelegate's view is never initialized. But when I do initialize it like in `loggingViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];` The `viewDidLoad` is never called!

Comment: Why is it never initialized? Any particular reason you are able to find? You should not do `loggingViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];` That will create more problems.

Comment: So, how am I supposed to initialize all of it's subViews?

Comment: Ideally it gets created by itself and in viewDidLoad you can create the subviews as shown in your question. I think the issue is that you are adding the loggingViewController.view as a subview to your delegete's self.view. I dont think that is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    loggingViewController = [[loggerViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = loggingViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

The reason for recursive calling is that your `self.view` is `nil` and hence it is try to call again and again when you are trying to add it as a subview of appdelegate's view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];
}
```

Comment: It is a bit more complex, I have a Tab Bar, and I want this specific view  to be placed on top of another view. How do I set up the controller and it's view so that I have all subviews set?

Comment: How about something like `[self.tabController presentModalViewController:loggingViewController animated:NO];`? You can check this as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406426/adding-login-screen-in-front-of-cocoa-touch-tab-bar-application-for-ios

Comment: I don't see where you are initializing your view btw. I don't see how I should initialize it.

Comment: in that example there is no initialization of the view. I must be missing something

Comment: You dont have to initialize your view. When you call `[super viewDidLoad];` it should initialize it for you. The problem in your case was that you are adding as a subview probably before this line is executed.

Comment: I have [super viewDidLoad], it is in viewDidLoad

Comment: Yes, so it should work fine, as long as  `[super viewDidLoad]` is called before using `[self.view addSubview..`

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:loggingViewController.view];` calls -> `loggingViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, which calls it's [super viewDidLoad] (which as you said should create the view), and then the first time there is a call for **self.view** the recursion happens

Comment: @Ted, In that case, try implementing loadView method alone and do self.view = [[UIView alloc] init..] inside the loadView method. Check if that helps. I would suggest you to still go for `[self.tabController presentModalViewController:loggingViewController animated:NO];` in app delegate class.