# Tab bar application with login view xcode 6 using storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement an application (Universal-both orientation supported) which is presenting a LoginViewController first and if login is successful, then show the tab bar controller using Xcode 6 and Storyboard. I have followed many related questions such as [Adding login screen in front of Cocoa Touch Tab Bar Application for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406426/adding-login-screen-in-front-of-cocoa-touch-tab-bar-application-for-ios) and [Showing login view controller before main tab bar controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716755/showing-login-view-controller-before-main-tab-bar-controller) which are pretty old.
This might sounds like very simple question but Im struggling to implement this feature since quite a while now.

Please provide me any sample project (or at least guidance) if anyone have done this kind of application using storyboard? And how to logout from the application when inside the tab bar controller (i.e. after logged-in) ? Hide Tab bar controller in some view controllers?

Comment: just add your storyboard elements and interfaces per usual, and check if a user is logged in, in `viewDidAppear` of your root view controller, and act accordingly.

Comment: Kanishka, your question requires a little long answer, for example, by using screenshots : it would require the creation of a viewcontroller with two textviews (for user and password) and one button, the code to check this data against the database, the creation of a second viewcontroller with the tab bar. Have you try youtube? It's plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Soulshined thank you for your answer. @Jose I just needed a guidance not a whole app with 2 textfield, anyway your answer helped me a lot and finally I was able to find it in youtube. Thank you very much!

Comment: Kanishka: would you please write the link of the youtube tutorial you followed? I need to do your same thing and I'm very new to swift and xcode 6

Comment: Lory: I have used this tutorial on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhZhtIXdMLI. Please let me know if you still need any help.